# Continuity of function-example

Tags: functions, calculus-and-analysis

I'd like to examine the continuity of the following function:

```
f[x_] := Limit[(n^x - n^(-x) ) / (n^x + n^(-x) ), n -> Infinity]
```

I know that this function isn't continuous because $f(x)=-1$ for $x<0$, for $x=0$ $f(x)=0$, and finally $f(x)=1$ for $x>0$ .

$$
x<0\quad \quad f(x)=-1 \\
x=0\quad \quad f(x)=\ \ \  0 \\
x>0\quad \quad f(x)=\  \ \ 1 \\
$$

I would rather have a more formal proof than my guess. Could someone give me a tip on how I can prove this using *Mathematica*?

Comment: In general, Mathematica does not generate formal proofs. Probably closest built-in Mma functionality gets to proving something in general sense is capability of generating counterexamples - but not finding counterexamples is not a formal proof, of course.

Comment: Oh, maybe I formed my question in wrong way. I don't need  exactly formal proof, but I just would like to make some calculations, how to show this discontinuity. For now I haven't idea how can I show that

Comment: My first suggestion would be finding a solution for `x` with `Solve`, looking for differing values of `Limit`s of `x` from different `Direction`s (1 and -1). This should be trivial, but I don't have Mathematica handy just now...

Comment: Generaly I'm able to compute Limits from different Directions, but how can I prove that I should find around x=0?

Comment: I'm not entirely certain what you are looking to prove. Is it that your assumptions hold, or to find locations of discontinuities, or something else altogether?

Comment: I have to examine continuity of funcion, so I tried to use instruction Limit as above. But I don't know what's next? For what I can deducate that this limit changes around x=0 exactly? Then I know that I can examine this limits around x=0 using Direction.

Comment: $n^x = e^{(\ln n) x}$, and $(e^y - e^{-y})/(e^y + e^{-y}) = \tanh y$.  So your function is just $\tanh( (\ln n) x)$.  This, along with the fact that $\tanh(\pm \infty) = \pm 1$ and $\tanh(0) = 0$, should be enough to prove your assertions.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I was looking for some transformation like the one you mentioned, but couldn't find any off the top of my head. Do you know whether *Mathematica* is aware of the identities you mentioned? If so, could you show how one could coax the system into simplifying the function under study? Maybe you could expand your comment into an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, I'm expanding on my comment above, in which I noted that
$$
\frac{n^{x} - n^{-x}}{n^x + n^{-x}} = \tanh [ (\ln n) x]
$$
If you want to coax Mathematica to show this for you, you have to be a little tricky.  In particular, Mathematica will automatically evaluate `Exp[Log[n] x]` into `n^x` unless you tell it not to.  However, if you `Hold` the expression, and apply the `ExpToTrig` function to it before you release the hold, you get the result above:

```
f[x] /. Power[n, x_] -> Exp[Hold[Log[n] x]]
ReleaseHold[ExpToTrig[%]]
```

[image]

[image]

Once you've done this, then Mathematica can handle the limits correctly:

```
Map[Limit[%, n -> Infinity, Assumptions -> #] &, {x > 0, x == 0, x < 0}]

(* {1, 0, -1} *)
```

I'm not sure this is a generally useful result—I had to kind of know where I was going in order to guide Mathematica there—but it's good to see that it can be done, at least.

Comment: Thank you for writing this up! I have found that I sometimes struggle mightily to manipulate expressions in *Mathematica*, even in those cases where I knew where to go, so I always appreciate seeing how others do it! (+1)

Answer (score 2):

`Limit` takes `Assumptions`

```
Clear[f]

f[x_] := Limit[(n^x - n^(-x))/(n^x + n^(-x)), n -> Infinity]

Assuming[{#}, f[x]] & /@ {x < 0, x == 0, x > 0}
```

> {-1, 0, 1}

```
Plot[f[x], {x, -5, 5}, Exclusions -> 0,
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[6], Point[{0, f[0]}]}]
```

[image]